# microsoft fakes only stub static property of a static class

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

Is it possible to shim a static property in a static class using Microsoft Fakes framework?

If not, Why would a stub work, but not a shim?

Here is my class code:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static List<string> greatStations = new List<string>();
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        var shim = new Fakes.ShimGlobals { };
        Fakes.StubGlobals.greatStations = new List<string>();
        // Next line complains that ShimGlobals does not contain a definition for 'greatStations'
        Fakes.ShimGlobals.greatStations = new List<string>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In your static class, greatStations isn't a property, it's a public field.

Comment: @BFree So you can only shim properties? But you can stub fields and properties?

Comment: I've only used fakes back when it was called Moles, and there I know it wasn't possible to stub out a field. I'm trying to find documentation that proves/disproves this.

Comment: Sidenote: Consider refactoring your code. If it needs to be replaced for testing, it shouldn't have been static in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Fakes, you can stub virtual properties and methods (of classes and interfaces). You can shim non-virtual properties and methods (instance and static). Fields don't need to be shimmed or stubbed because they can be set directly, as shown below.

```
Globals.greatStations = new List<string>();
```

Comment: So when you "Add Fakes Assembly", it will not generate fakes for any fields. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Fields can be accessed directly and don't need fakes.